# md-menu behaviour in Angular Material

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I Would like to have multiple md-menus and make each one open closing the other not having to close the already opened one first?
how to change the default behaviour?

Here is a fiddle to illustrate: https://jsfiddle.net/w1pf0et5/

```
<body ng-app="BlankApp" ng-cloak>

<md-menu md-offset="10 60" >
            <!-- Trigger element is a md-button with an icon -->
            <md-button ng-click="$mdOpenMenu($event)" aria-label="Open sample menu">
            open first
            </md-button>
            <md-menu-content width="6" id="messages">

                <md-menu-item md-menu-origin md-menu-align-target ><md-button ng-click="doSomething()">
                    Test 1
                </md-button></md-menu-item>

                <md-menu-item><md-button ng-click="doSomething()">
                    Test 2
                </md-button></md-menu-item>

                <md-menu-item><md-button ng-click="doSomething()">
                   Test 3
                </md-button></md-menu-item>

                <md-menu-item><md-button ng-click="doSomething()">
                   Test 4
                </md-button></md-menu-item>

            </md-menu-content>
        </md-menu>

        <md-menu md-offset="10 60" >
            <!-- Trigger element is a md-button with an icon -->
            <md-button ng-click="$mdOpenMenu($event)" aria-label="Open sample menu">
            open second
            </md-button>
            <md-menu-content width="6" id="messages">

                <md-menu-item md-menu-origin md-menu-align-target ><md-button ng-click="doSomething()">
                    Test 1
                </md-button></md-menu-item>

                <md-menu-item><md-button ng-click="doSomething()">
                    Test 2
                </md-button></md-menu-item>

                <md-menu-item><md-button ng-click="doSomething()">
                   Test 3
                </md-button></md-menu-item>

                <md-menu-item><md-button ng-click="doSomething()">
                   Test 4
                </md-button></md-menu-item>

            </md-menu-content>
        </md-menu>

        <script>
            angular.module('BlankApp', ['ngMaterial']);

        </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `md-menu-bar` with `md-toolbar` to get the desired result and you must use `button` in place of `md-button` for opening menu(Trigger Element). Check the following pen for example.

http://codepen.io/next1/pen/vGXOaY

Comment: Thanks !! That's really great but there is something about it too when I open a menu and with just hovering it switches to the other, how to make it with click only if possible?

Comment: You want to disable the hovering effect?  do you want  more than 1 menu to be open?

Comment: Nope I just want 1 menu open and to open when clicked only if possible, not open when hovering that's not desired and thanks in advance

Comment: I think its feasible solution to let user click only once and then hover if wants to open another menu rather than clicking again.

Comment: You are absolutely right but I was just asking anyway if you happen to know?

Comment: Nope. I never seen that kind of menu. I think all the application uses that first click and then hover concept.

Comment: hmmm have you seen facebook's ? when you view your notifications or messages or friend requests

Comment: I dont think It is called menu. https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/menus.html#menus-usage see the specification.

Comment: oh I get it, Thank you very much.

Comment: No problem my friend :)